# Building PyDas using Anaconda on Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-8.1, ipython, cython

I am trying to build **PyDas** using  Anaconda with the code

```
cd /c/PyDAS 
python setup.py install
```

but I receive the error

> ImportError:No module named Cython.Distutils

The file for cython and all the distutils are in the anaconda folder and perhaps it is looking in ipython or something. I am using python27 for this now but I also have python34 installed on the computer.
I also am trying to build and install **PyQED** and **RMG-Py** and I receive the same error whenever I input the code provided to build and install.

Comment: Also I have windows 8.1

Comment: Is cython definitely installed in the relevant conda environment? What do you see if you run `python -c "import Cython.Distutils"`? It might be finding another copy of Python instead of Anaconda's Python.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's installed with it. I thought when I installed conda it installed cython with it. I also tried to download cython separate but it made no difference.

Comment: and when I put that in I receive 
Traceback (most recent call last)
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils

Comment: I have the same issue with Anaconda + win 8.1. Did you find out how to resolve this?